# Error with react-native-video and ReNative when using the Video component

Tags: react-native, tizen, android-tv

I am working with a library called ReNative to deploy a React Native application to multiple platforms.

I am doing the tests on a **Tizen** and **Android Tv** emulators.

Creating an app with the basic blank template works with no problems.

But after installing the **react-native-video** plugin (using `rnv plugin add`) and using the `Video` component I get the following error when lauching the application with `rnv run -p tizen` (or `androidtv`):

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/react-native-video/Video.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-native/Libraries/Image/resolveAssetSource' in 'C:\dev\ReactNativeVideoReNative\node_modules\react-native-video'
 @ ./node_modules/react-native-video/Video.js 4:47-105
 @ ./src/app.js
 @ ./index.tizen.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:8087 (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./index.tizen.js

ERROR in ./src/assets/BigBuckBunny.mp4 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character ' ' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
 @ ./src/app.js 7:41-77
 @ ./index.tizen.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:8087 (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./index.tizen.js
```

Or if you want to see a screenshot:
https://prnt.sc/rg3c1f

Here is an screenshot of the code: https://prnt.sc/rg3gm9

I literally have zero experience with this tool. So, if there is any information that is missing or that you need, tell me.